# $select and $expand break ODataQueryOptions -- how to fix?

Tags: c#, select, asp.net-web-api, odata, expand

We are using Microsoft ASP.NET MVC OData WebAPI for our web services. Because of some data architecture issues surrounding hierarchy ID (which are outside the scope of this conversation), some of our GET operations have to use ODataQueryOptions and manually manipulate the expression to add additional restrictions. We do so like this (error handling code removed and calls to other methods inlined for clarity):

```
public IQueryable<Person> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Person> oDataQueryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<Person> result;
    IQueryable<Person> dataSet = context.Persons;

    var tempQuery = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(dataSet).Cast<Person>();
    var modifier = new HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor(GetDescendantsOfNode, GetAncestorsOfNode);
    var expression = modifier.ModifyHierarchyNodeExpression(tempQuery.Expression);

    result = context.Persons.Provider.CreateQuery<Person>(expression);

    return result;
}
```

This has worked great for some time, but we've been eagerly awaiting select-and-expand so that we can better control the data we receive from our services. Monday we updated our dev environment to WebApi OData 5.0.0-rc1 and got select-and-expand working, but we can't use it against these services that use ODataQueryOptions. We can only use it against our other services. If we query the code above using `$select` and/or `$expand`, we get the following error:

```
"message": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
"type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"stacktrace": "",
"internalexception":
{
    "message": "Unable to cast the type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand`1' to type 'OurCompany.Domains.Data.Models.Person'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.",
    "type": "System.NotSupportedException",
    "stacktrace": " at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.CastMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert() at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference feedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext) at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders) at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__10.MoveNext()"
}
```

I've done some Googling and stumbled upon [this](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$select%20and%20$expand%20support&referringTitle=Specs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569779/implementing-select-with-webapi-and-odataqueryoptions), but neither were helpful. Nobody appears to be doing quite what we're doing and trying to use select-and-expand. How do we fix this? I'm at a loss here...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code,

```
var tempQuery = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(dataSet).Cast<Person>();
```

The Cast is invalid as once `$select` and `$expand` are applied the result is no longer a Person. It would be a `Wrapper<Person>` that contains only the properties that the client asked for. You might have to modify your `HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor` to take this into consideration.

Also, try changing your action to this to handle the fact that the result might not be a `IQueryable<Person>` anymore.

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Person> oDataQueryOptions)
    {
        IQueryable result;
        IQueryable<Person> dataSet = context.Persons;

        IQueryable tempQuery = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(dataSet);
        var modifier = new HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor(GetDescendantsOfNode, GetAncestorsOfNode);
        var expression = modifier.ModifyHierarchyNodeExpression(tempQuery.Expression);

        result = context.Persons.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);

        return Ok(result, result.GetType());
    }

    private IHttpActionResult Ok(object content, Type type)
    {
        Type resultType = typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType, content, this) as IHttpActionResult;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't appear this is actually the case. When I step through with the debugger, the result is a `Person`, not a `Wrapper<Person>`. In fact, the exception is not thrown anywhere in my method. The exception is thrown AFTER the method returns.

Comment: LINQ queries are almost always lazily evaluated. So, the exception would be thrown when somebody tries to enumerate the result not when the query is applied. This means that the exception would be thrown in the formatter when it is writing the response to the stream. The exception message is very clear about what is happening

""Unable to cast the type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand`1' to type 'OurCompany.Domains.Data.Models.Person'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. I should have thought about the fact that it would have been evaluated later. However, I can't understand what would need to change about the `HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor`. It's generic--it doesn't act just on `Person`. The `ModifyHierarchyNodeExpression` method is just calling the standard `Visit` method. It's not doing anything else. Importantly, none of the other code in the visitor is getting invoked for this simple `$filter`. On the basic query that's failing with this error (unique key ==), the visitor is a no-op.

Comment: I didn't realize that the visitor is generic. I updated my answer with some sample code that you could try in that case.

Comment: That's it! It worked! Thank you very much! You were a huge help.

Comment: Where is `HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor`? Nowhere to be found.

Comment: I have the same problem as parliament... where is the HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor?

Comment: @parliament how did ya fix this, or was it left hung like the parliament in my country?