# OData using $expand breaks cast operation due to wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm experiencing the same problem as addressed [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880783/1267778)

However, the answer is not sufficient for me. First of all I cannot for the life of me find `HierarchyNodeExpressionVisitor` in OData 5.0.0 (not RC1) (or anywhere for that matter, tried googling around).

Second even if I did find it returning `IHttpActionResult` is not good enough, I need to return a typed `PageResult<MyViewModel>`

The stated justificiation to return `IHttpActionResult` is "to handle the fact that the result might not be a `IQueryable<MyEntity>` anymore." once the $expand operator is used.

But this doesn't make sense to me because I thought the $expand operator is used to include a navigation property on entity just like a server side `Include(e => e.RelatedProperty)` would. At least in my case I'm only including a property already on the Entity so I don't have to worry about it "potentially being something else".

However when using `$expand=Department` I cannot `Cast<>()` to the entity type because it cannot cast `SelectAllAndExpand<MyEntity>` to a `MyEntity`.

How can I "unwrap" the expand back to the original entity so that I can do a projection?

```
public PageResult<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel> GetDatesWithDepartments(ODataQueryOptions<DateSnippet> options)
{
    IQueryable query = options.ApplyTo(_context.DateSnippets, new ODataQuerySettings());;

    //Exception when using $expand.. cannot cast SelectAllAndExpand<DateSnippet> to DateSnippet
    List<DateSnippet> dateSnippets = query.Cast<DateSnippet>().ToList();

    var dateSnippetsViewModels = (from d in dateSnippets
                                    select new DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel
                                    {
                                        ...
                                    });

    var result = new PageResult<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel>(
            dateSnippetsViewModels as IEnumerable<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel>,
            Request.GetNextPageLink(),
            Request.GetInlineCount());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You might want to take a look at this though. http://beyondtheduck.com/revisting-projecting-and-the-odata-expand-query-option/

Comment: What does your DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel and DateSnippets look like?

Comment: When you expand a type, you need to have a virtual collection (usually an `IEnumberable<Type>` or `SingleResult<Type>` property in the top level object. Then expanding will apply the relation foreign_key data and your original object will have it's property "expanded" with the relational data. 

Of course this all depends on the version of OData, and if it's a Standalone or WCF service instance.  Different rules for different platforms sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We've since abandoned OData because all it was really doing for us was allowing us to create less API endpoint at the cost of moving more data processing to the client. That realization and the lack of support made us stick with plain web api endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hopefully should work, by the time we get to the Enumerator, the result should be a `DateSnippet`. What you were doing before was trying to cast in the Linq Expression tree. I suspect in the IQueryable Execute, that is resolved and converted as opposed to cast.

```
public PageResult<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel> GetDatesWithDepartments(ODataQueryOptions<DateSnippet> options)
{
    IQueryable query = options.ApplyTo(_context.DateSnippets, new ODataQuerySettings());;

    List<DateSnippet> dateSnippets = new List<DateSnippet>();
    foreach(DateSnippet item in query)
    {
        dateSnippets.Add(item);
    }

    var dateSnippetsViewModels = (from d in dateSnippets
                                    select new DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel
                                    {
                                        ...
                                    });

    var result = new PageResult<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel>(
            dateSnippetsViewModels as IEnumerable<DateSnippetWithDepartmentsViewModel>,
            Request.GetNextPageLink(),
            Request.GetInlineCount());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me with Microsoft.OData.Core.7.0.0 once the $expand parameter is used. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) _The IQueryable interface is intended for implementation by query providers. It is only supposed to be implemented by providers that also implement IQueryable<T>._ Apparently this is not the case here because a cast of 'query' to IQueryable<T> fails.