# MapODataRoute and ODataQueryOptions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Im building a WebAPI OData solution that handles untyped entity objects, as described in [this excellent post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/leohu/archive/2013/11/05/typeless-entity-object-support-in-webapi.aspx). Like that post, I define my EdmModel upfront, and use the MapODataRoute method and pass in the model to use:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", ModelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
```

However, this does not seem to work with ODataQueryOptions parameter in my methods:

```
Get(ODataQueryOptions query)
{
}
```

It gives the following error: *The given model does not contain the type 'System.Web.Http.OData.IEdmEntityObject'. Parameter name: elementClrType*

Is there any way to get ODataQueryOptions to work with MapODataRoute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build the ODataQueryOptions manually in your controller action in untyped mode. Sample code follows,

```
ODataPath path = Request.GetODataPath();
IEdmType edmType = path.EdmType;

IEdmType elementType = edmType.TypeKind == EdmTypeKind.Collection 
    ? (edmType as IEdmCollectionType).ElementType.Definition 
    : edmType;

// build the typeless query options using the element type.
ODataQueryContext queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(Request.GetEdmModel(), elementType);
ODataQueryOptions queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);
```

Comment: Hi Raghuram, thanks for your answer, that is exactly what ive been doing, see the code in my answer. It throws an error with $select and $expand though...

Comment: As a side note, it appears that if you're doing this you also don't need to define the returned collection as `IQueryable`. I was getting tripped up w/ serialization errors until I went back to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Note that for later versions, this method is marked as obsolete.  Use `System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.ODataProperties(request).Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to do it as follows:

```
ODataPath path = Request.GetODataPath();
IEdmType edmType = path.EdmType;   

private ODataQueryOptions GetODataQueryOptions(IEdmType edmType)
    {
        IEdmModel model = Models.ModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        ODataQueryContext queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, edmType);
        ODataQueryOptions queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, this.Request);

        return queryOptions;
    }
```

This works for most query options, but crashes with $select and $expand: *The type 'Collection([Org.Microsoft.Product Nullable=False])' is not an entity type. Only entity types support $select and $expand.* Is there a way to avoid this exception gracefully when a client tries to filter with $select and $expand, or should i just write something like

```
if (Request.RequestUri.Query.Contains("select")) { return errormessage }
```

Also, and more importantly, how would one apply these query options to an *EdmEntityObjectCollection* which gets returned in the first method?

```
queryOptions.ApplyTo(collectionProduct.AsQueryable()); // wont work...
```

(perhaps it is better practice to dynamically build your collection in regards to the query options anyway)

Comment: The edmType that you pass to the `ODataQueryContext` is the element type. So, if the `ODataPath.EdmType` is a collection you should get the element type out and use it. I will update my answer to take care of this.

Comment: Also, regarding the ApplyTo. We don't support ApplyTo on untyped ODataQueryOptions as there is no CLR type involved and IQueryable<T> requires a CLR type. So, you should apply the ODataQueryOptions yourself on your backend and then convert the result into an `EdmEntityObjectCollection`. This blog post could guide you somewhat - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx

Comment: Hi RaghuRam, is there a way implement $select with untyped collections? $filter works ok, but when we loop over our data and only TrySetPropertyValue the properties in the $select-clause, the complete EdmEntityObject (with all properties) is returned, instead of an EdmEntityObject with only the selected properties. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: found your answer in another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18603494/1197130