# How to Instantiate ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a working (simplified) `ODataController` with the following method.

```
public class MyTypeController : ODataController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [EnableQuery]
  [ODataRoute("myTypes")]
  public IQueryable<MyType> GetMyTypes(ODataQueryOptions<MyType> options)
  {
    return _repo.myResultsAsQueryable();
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to call this method from the server and to do this I need to instantiate an `ODataQueryOptions` which requires an `ODataQueryContext`.

There are examples of how to do this (Eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951261/mapodataroute-and-odataqueryoptions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197041/reconstructing-an-odataqueryoptions-object-and-getinlinecount-returning-null)) but they all seem to reference a previous version of OData. The [ODataQueryContext](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/ODataQueryContext.cs) constructor currently requires a third argument (`ODataPath` path) which is not addressed in any examples that I can find.

**Edit:** 
@snow_FFFFFF, Here's some more context... I realize that I can simply consume the OData endpoint via a HttpClient but I would like to interact with the IQueryable directly as you say.

The problem is that the application I'm working on allows users to create filters (like a sophisticated search engine) that can be saved and later recalled by other users. From a JS client, they simply lookup the filter by id, and issue a query against the OData endpoint with the filter applied to the query string. This works very well from the client-side but I would like to be able to do something similar from the server-side as well.

This is what I would like to do but how can I instantiate the ODataPath argument?

```
public IQueryable<MyType> FilterMyTypes(int filterID)
{
  // lookup filter by filterID from db...
  filter = "$filter=Status eq 1"; // for example...

  ODataPath path = // but how can I get the path!!!
  new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(MyType), path); 

  var uri = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:56339/mytypes?" + filter);
  var opts = new ODataQueryOptions<MyType>(ctx, uri);

  var results = new MyTypeController().GetMyTypes(opts);
}
```

Another application of this would be to support dynamic grouping as below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("myTypes/{filterID:int}/groupby/{groupByFieldName}")]
public IHttpActionResult GroupMyTypes(int filterID, string groupByFieldName)
{
  // For example: get all Active MyTypes and group by AssignedToUserID...

  // Get the results of the filter as IQueryable...
  var results = FilterMyTypes(filterID);

  // group on groupByFieldName
  var grouped = results.GroupBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x,groupByFieldName));

  // select the groupByFieldName and the count
  var transformedResults = grouped.Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

  return Ok(transformedResults);
}
```

Comment: In http://github.com/OData/WebApi, there's a lot of test cases that you can refer to. For example, ODataQueryContext, you can refer to: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/UnitTest/System.Web.OData.Test/OData/Query/ODataQueryContextTests.cs#L181-L200

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll try that.. Not used to MS having open source...

Comment: Sam. You're awesome! If you put that in an answer, I can accept it. Thanks so much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. ODataPath is a list of ODataPathSegment(s) which should follow up the [OData Uri spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398265).

In Web API OData, it's easy to instantiate an ODataPath, for example:

```
IEdmModel model = GetEdmModel(); 
IEdmEntitySet entitySet = model.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet(setName); 
ODataPath path = new ODataPath(new EntitySetPathSegment(entitySet));
```

The above `path` follows up the OData spec that it has the odata template as:

```
~/entityset
```

More test cases (codes) can be found [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/d02bc61ea7b31ada1e54abbeebbecb3c5df0e3ac/test/UnitTest/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Test.Shared/Query/ODataQueryContextTests.cs)

Comment: As of 1/25/2017 the latest stable version of `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` is v6.0.0. It seems like there is no longer an `EntitySetPathSegment` class. I needed to downgrade in NuGet to 5.9.1. Otherwise, VERY helpful question, and I really appreciated the link to source code test cases.

Comment: borked link as of today.

Comment: what is setName?

Comment: @anisanwesley the setName can be any entity set defined in your model.

Comment: @SamXu, Is it possible to add updates to reflect your solution in the context of Odata 7.4.0 release?

Comment: this is not working on my side. the classes always needs some parameters that I dont even know where to get those

Answer (score -1):

Your odata controller is providing an HTTP interface to your data, shouldn't you access it via HTTP (even if from the server)?  There is a VS add-in to generate odata client code here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937

Or, if you are doing this from within the same project, why not a common method that returns the IQueryable that could be called from your code or from the controller?

**UPDATE**: Based on more information in the original question:

If you have ODataQueryOptions defined in a controller method, it will allow you to parse the well-formed odata query that is calling that method.  I have used this when I needed to translate parts of an odata query because I needed to query multiple data sources to return the final result.

It sounds like you want something that takes non-odata parameters and options.  For this, you probably need to look at custom Actions and or Functions (if you are just returning data, probably a function):

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

**UPDATE #2**: And after more detailed reading, I think I missed your point - I don't have the answer, but I'll play around with it.  Can't you just reform the URL itself (as opposed to instantiating the query options?

**UPDATE #3**: I think you are going to have a hard time tricking it into thinking it is getting an odata request...that isn't really an odata request.  Back to the second option mentioned in my original answer - why not a common method that you can use and the odata controller can use - something like this:

```
// some sort of helper class
public class HelperObject
{
    public static IQueryable<MyType> GetGroupedValues(int filterID, string groupByFieldName)
    {
        // all your code/logic here
    }
}

// your odata controller uses the helper
[HttpGet]
[Route("myTypes/{filterID:int}/groupby/{groupByFieldName}")]
public IHttpActionResult GroupMyTypes(int filterID, string groupByFieldName)
{
    return Ok(HelperObject.GetGroupedValues(filterID, groupByFieldName));
}

// ... and so does your other code that wants to do the same thing
var x = HelperObject.GetGroupedValues(filterID, groupByFieldName);
```